# Configuration Transaction hibernate4 and spring3

Tags: spring, hibernate

i'm new with Hibernate and Spring.
I have a problem with my spring configuration about the "transactionManager".

There is my bean configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql:T"/>
<property name="username" value="postgres"/>
<property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="annotatedClasses">
<list>
<value>com.model.Cours</value>
<value>com.model.Student</value>
<value>com.model.Teacher</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.model"/>
</beans>
```

> the message is relativ on 
>   :Error occured processing XML  > 'org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor'.
>   See Error Log for more details

Comment: My suggestion would be to *see Error Log for more details*.

Comment: Also, if your goal is to use hibernate4, you shouldn't use any class from the hibernate3 package.